# GUI to UDP (via javascript? node.js and express maybe?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, sockets

I'll try to make things a little bit clearer here.

What i want to archieve is:

A little GUI with some sliders to drag around.
After one of the sliders is changed, a UDP Stream to the localhost shall be created and a string containing the actual values of all sliders shall be send to the localhost.

In the future this application needs to be expanded and accessible from the web, so my guess is to create it as a html file with javascript in it.

I dont know if this is possible at all, i have read somewhere that javascript "as is" cant handle UDP. After some.. (a lot) google research i found node.js and express. So far i was able to set up a simple server, handling some  elements. Still getting values out of the JQuery Sliders into the node.js is still a riddle to me.

My Question is: Am I on the right path? Or utterly lost?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Giant walls of code like this generally don't get a lot of attention, try and narrow down your question to only the code that's causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, websockets are the correct tool for brwoser->server stream communication. What do you need UDP for? The node.js server would need to act as a middleman.

Comment: phew :) at least im on the right track it seems :)

Comment: I have a big simulator here and we are feeding it with "orders" from other programs  (autopilot tools etc). Interface is UDP only, so no other protocol possible.
So far im using "Jquery" for the slider elements, trying to feed them over to the "node.js" via the "express web application framework". Then i  make node.js send the whole package via udp (which looks rather "easy to do"). Do i need all of those components for the task?
Thx alot so far :)